# How to make openapi-generator to change default JMeter variables, CSV content?

Tags: jmeter, yaml, openapi-generator

I am trying to make JMeter test plan based on API defined in YAML but I wish I was able to define my default params and their values.

Is there a way to generate *.jmx with my own params, values and even CSV content? E.g. I wish I could set my own host in config (not localhost by default), testCases (in fact loop number) or even my own JMeter samples.

Comment: Ok, I've found some data which helps me to answer myself :-)
There are sources of opengenerator-api on github and there's a template - so a subject to modify as needed. Moreover 'localhost' and other parameters in template are JMeter properties which can be modified when JMeter is started in CLI. The same relates to CSV content.

Comment: It seems like you'd need to create a custom generator to do this. You _might_ be able to reuse an existing generator and modify the templates to achieve your desired output (see https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/customization).

Comment: Yup, I did so. I passed the matter to my fellow programmer but the guide is missing detalils. There are sike environment dependencies not mentioned. I'm sure he will deal with it.

Comment: If you open a ticket with details about missing environment concerns, we'll get the docs updated. We do have a docker container which will allow you to choose without changes to your host environment (see the project README for running in docker).